# If $\boldsymbol{v}\cdot\boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{w}\cdot\boldsymbol{x}$ for all $\boldsymbol{x}$ then $\boldsymbol{v}=\boldsymbol{w}$

Tags: geometry, vectors

I'm not sure how to tackle this one. Let $\boldsymbol{v}$,$\boldsymbol{w}$ be vectors. Show that if $\boldsymbol{v}\cdot\boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{w}\cdot\boldsymbol{x}$ for all vector $\boldsymbol{x}$ then $\boldsymbol{v} = \boldsymbol{w}$.

Comment: I'm a first year Maths student so this may need to be explained in basic terms

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Have you tried collecting terms on one side of the equation?  It's always a good idea to give an indication of how you approached an assignment and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are first year, I have to guess that you're working with the ordinary inner product which is positive definite, that is, $v\cdot v\geq 0$ with equality iff $v=0$. Here's a solution that doesn't need to refer to bases.

By bilinearity, that would mean $(v-w)\cdot x=0$ for all $x$. In particular, $(v-w)\cdot(v-w)=0$. But as I mentioned in the assumptions above, there is only one vector satisfying $z\cdot z=0$: the zero vector. So $v-w=0$ and you have your answer.

Comment: This is beyond the scope of the original post, I guess, but other readers might be interested in knowing that beyond positive definite inner products, there are things called *nondegenerate bilinear forms* which are generalizations. The nondegeneracy condition is exactly that $v\cdot x=0$ for all $x\in V$ implies that $v=0$. An example of a degenerate bilinear form would be $(x_1, y_1)\cdot(x_2,y_2)=x_1x_2$, and $v=(1,1)$ and $w=(1,0)$ have the property that $v\cdot x=w\cdot x$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:  What happens when you take the dot product with the standard unit vectors?

Comment: It's a good way to think about the information given in the problem, but so terse I think this works better as a comment.